# Using JWT authentication with Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm trying to build JWT Authentication for my application using Laravel's latest version. But I can't get it to work with the "tymon/jwt-auth" that everyone seems to be using. I don't think there is a version compatible with the latest Laravel yet. Now I was wondering if it's possible to use JWT Authentication with Laravel Passport? If anyone knows a way to make it possible, please tell me!

Comment: I am using jwt with laravel 5.4 and it works like charm. What version of oft `jwt-auth`is in your `composer.json` file? And what do you mean with "can't get it to work"? What have you tried?

Comment: Tried installing it, everything seemed to work fine until I tried opening one of my API functions in postman. This is the error: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found. 
I installed using the wiki so I guess this would be the version:
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"

Comment: have you added `Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class`to your `config/app.php` file? The installation guide is still for laravel 5.2 or so... . I used this guide for 5.4 and it worked: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/860

Comment: FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 208:
Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found

Started getting code errors as soon as I started modifying "/app/http/Controller/auth/LoginController.php" according to the guide..